# Postgres Template Access Privileges

Tags: postgresql

I am currently making a website using node.js/PostgreSQL, and it needs to create copies of a template database that has many specific access privileges, or otherwise it won't work properly. I am currently using this query to do it:

```
CREATE DATABASE test WITH TEMPLATE db_template OWNER user1
```

This works really well, except for the fact that the access privileges for the database object do not copy over. I was hoping someone knew of a way to make it so the template also copies over the privileges, or a query to copy privileges from one database to another.

Comment: This looks like a pure PostgreSQL question, and not related to `pg-promise` framework, which simply executes your queries.

Comment: But permissions and ownership of objects *inside* the database *are* copied over, just not the permissions on the database object itself. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to copy over the permissions on the database object itself.